# In Ember how do I access an attribute from a different model from the current handlebar in the html file?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, model

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{{#if model.user.isAdmin}}
<div>
 My name is {{model.user.name}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

inside a handlebar from a controller not related to users:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="events/new">
```

How would I go about this? How can I use/show the values from another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in several ways.

If your new event route is a child route of for example the user route (nested within your router) you can do:

```
// events/new controller
Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['user'] // a reference to the user controller
});

// events/new template
{{ controllers.user.model.name }}
```

If it is not a child route, you can access the user model by calling the store:

```
// events/new route
Ember.Route.extend({
    // use the user model as your model
    model: function() {
        // load a user by its id, or remove the id to load all users
        return this.store.find('user',1);
    }
});

// events/new template
{{ model.name }}
```

Or you can use multiple models in the `events/new` route:

```
// events/new route
Ember.Route.extend({
    // return multiple models
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            event: this.store.createRecord('event', {
                // add event properties here if needed
            }),
            user: this.store.find('user',1),
            ...
        });
    }
});

// events/new template
{{ model.user.name }}
```

As you can see, it depends on the relationship of your routes and the structure of your app.

Comment: My user model has no controllers as it is populated with information sent from the api and there is no relationship whatsoever between user and events

Comment: In that case you can use the store to get the user as I mentioned above (if you know the id).